# Why is Eclipse exporting sources in war?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to export a WAR in eclipse, from a maven project. when I click File > Export > War File, then a dialog is show with the option "Include source Files". This option is not checked (is a checkbox) and eclipse is still exporting the WAR with the source files. I also tried, to check that option and still output the war with the source. I am running Indigo on Linux 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've the same problem. Looks like a bug which is already reported to the eclipse team :

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386069
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389715

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Eclipse Java EE Juno release on win7 64bit, and it is ok with the Eclipse Java EE Indigo release, so I think it is a bug of Eclipse Java EE Juno release.

Comment: I temp solved it with 'Run as: Maven Package'. What about not maven projects?. But this is because I have a manven project. The thing is eclipse does have a checkbox that says 'Export sources'. So if I didnt check it, sources should be excluded on deployment. But they aren't.