# Java Source is Included in Exported WAR file when "Export source files" is unchecked

Tags: java, eclipse, export, war

I'm using Eclipse Juno EE IDE.  The .java files are being deployed to WEB-INF/classes with the .class files following a WAR file export.  I want to *exclude* the .java source-files from being deployed.

During export, in the export dialogue **"Export source files" *is unchecked***.

Yes, this is similar to a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462200/eclipse-including-java-source-code-files-with-class-files-in-war), but that answer did not work:  the obvious unchecking of the "Export source files" did not change the output.

Is there a project-level or general preference that is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Eclipse Juno version, fixed in a [patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389715#c4) and later releases.  The bug is documented here:  "[WAR export from IDE always includes java source - ignoring 'export source files'](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389715)".  This is similar to a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211462/why-is-eclipse-exporting-sources-in-war).